# Is there a method to omit time intervals in plot.zoo function of R?

Tags: r

I have a time series of zoo and POSIXct class using second intervals. However, as is usually the case in financial time series, there are often long time gaps without information (ex. overnight). When using plot.zoo, the useful (populated) intervals appear scrunched relative to the unused intervals. Is there some way to simply omit time intervals in the plotting function of plot.zoo().  P.S. It's possible to just simply plot the continuous time series (plot(ts(obj)), but then the time information is lost on the x axis.

@AndresT Thanks for the idea, but the data is already filtered. It is the plot.zoo() function that appears to be padding unused sample intervals to keep the total x range
active.  Pls see example below.

```
library(zoo)
st<-Sys.time()
t<-c(st, st+500, st+1000, st+1500, st+2000, st+90000, st+95000, st+100000)
rn<-runif(7)
zr<-zoo(rn, order.by=t)
plot.zoo(zr,type='o')
```

compare to the uniform spacing from plot(ts(data))

```
layout(1:2)
plot.zoo(zr, type='o')
plot(ts(zr),type='o')
```

So I would like to basically have the 2nd ts plot, but labeled with the corresponding x-axis labels from the 1st plot.zoo() function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(quantmod)
chartSeries(zr)
```